# How to convert an object dtype column to int16 in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert an object dtpye column to int16 in pandas dataframe.
Whereas my columns has data as shown below:
The values are present as string and has trailing spaces.

```
dict = {'age' : [' 35', ' 23', ' 22', ' 24', ' 65', ' 28', ' 25', ' 26', ' 53', ' 27', ' 32', ' 37',' NA',  '102', '104', '111', '107', '109', '105', '112', '115', '110', '116', '108', '113', 37, 81, 43, 30, 45, 41,67,59,46]
       }

data =pd.DataFrame(data = dict, columns =['age'])
```

i have replaced the ' NA' value to 'None'(as it would be  an null value to python.

```
data = data.replace({' NA': None })
```

and thereafter i have used `data = data.replace({' NA': None })`

but its not working and also i have a point here,  I have removed trailing spaces and tried but it was not working.

Comment: I see no code that would refer to dtypes or `int16` conversion here...

Comment: why bother with that aount of data? there are tons of posts on "how to convert pandas columns to int" posts here ... why ask again?